# How to detect different patterns in data columns

Tags: python, pandas

I try to improve my data cleaning process and try to come up with an approach to detect different patterns/formats within data columns in Pandas. The data I use is constantly changing, therefore I cannot work with static/pre-assigned patterns. So far the existing stackoverflow posts and Google did not help...

**Example 1st column:**

- 4758
- 4957
- 5768
- 2859028
- 3894820
- 3949
- 4954859
- ...

The column contains only integers. Here I would like to count the number of variations (i.e. different length of strings / number of digits). In the example: 2 variations, i.e. 4 digits and 7 digits.

**Example 2nd column:**

- Text1234
- 1234Text
- 11Text22
- 1Text234
- 4Text321
- ...

The column contains a mix of digits and letters. Although the string length is identical, the pattern is different, i.e. 4 letters followed by 4 digits; 4 digits followed by 4 letters, and so on. Is there a way or a python library to detect those non-matching patterns?

**Example 3rd column:**

- 31-12-2019
- 31_12_2019
- 31.12.2019
- 01-01-2020
- 02.02.2020
- 03_03_2020
- ...

Similar problem here: the string length is identical but the date format is varying, i.e. with _, - and .
Same question, is there a way to detect non-matching patterns?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can use a lot of regular expressions to match all your patterns. Say your 2nd column, there are patterns like '[a-zA-z]{4}\d{4}' and '\d{4}[a-zA-z]{4}'. Search more on regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I use regex already in other parts of my code. However, the data I use is constantly changing, therefore the patterns are always changing and I cannot declare a static pattern like you suggested...

Comment: All your samples here can be covered by regex. If you want something more complicated, please state examples in your post.